# Use of ImageButton without ImageURL to display the image

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton, imageurl

I need to use the asp control "ImageButton" in order to have access to the properties "OnClick" and "OnClientClick"

The problem is i cannot give any ImageURL since my Image is in Database.

I used this previously :

```
              <telerik:RadBinaryImage runat="server" ID="RadBinaryImage1" DataValue='<%#Eval("Image") %>'
                    AutoAdjustImageControlSize="false" Width="90px" Height="110px"  Enabled="true"  AlternateText="pas d'image"/>
```

But i don't have any Datavalue property in ImageButton control...

How can i manage to do this using ImageButton?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Generic Handler file and call that as your ImageUrl like:

```
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("Image.ashx?id={0}", eval("ID")) %>' />
```

Read more on how to do this here:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=129

---

The fact its an `ImageButton` makes no difference. It's the fact you want to render an image from image data type. I believe generating the image on the fly using a Generic Handler file is the most common way.

Comment: Thanks,
Is there any chance to make it work just by including my ImageButton within a LinkButton which has the Click properties ?
THX

Answer (score 0):

You can use handler for creating image from database or from binary format and this handler you can call from your imagebutton -> imageURL and it will show the image on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You may provide a method that will return an image as stream. Your URL may be:

http://www.yourwebsite.com/Application/Images/GetImage?name=myImageName&format=png

Inside your site you'll provide a GetImage page to query the database and write in the output stream the image data (do not forget to set the mime type).